# Can I stop the logged-in user from selecting other users in the author dropdown?

Tags: entries, users

I have a member group that has very fine grain options when they log in. They should only be able to add, edit, and delete their own entries in a single channel. At the moment they can select any user as the author. Is it possible to not allow them to change the author?

Comment: Sorry if I got overzealous with my edit!

Comment: No problem Matt :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> They should only be able to add, edit, and delete their own entries in a single channel.

You can currently to this by granting "Edit Entries", "Create Entries", "Publish Live Changes" and "Delete Entries" permission to a user.

However, none of those affect what shows up in the "Authors" drop down and I'm not sure they should.  Technically, changing the author of an entry is still editing the entry.

Maybe what's needed here is an additional permission under "Edit Entries" called "Change Entry Author".

Comment: I think a "Change Entry Author" option would be nice. :)

Comment: Thanks Brad, yeah I think it would be really good to have the option to change the entry author. For example if you have my set up and a user does change the author the entry then disappears (which is correct) as it is no longer an entry that is authored by themselves. The only way to put it back is for a user with the correct privileges to change the author.